# Site definition configuration. Multi feature visibility dependency

Tags: onet

I have created a new site defenition and I would like to set a feature dependency. There are a attribute that is called VisibilityFeatureDependency. As I understand, if I set this attribute, my template is shouwn only when the dependency feature is acivated. But it works only with one feature. My question is if I would like to have several feature dependencies, how could I do this?

I do not like to write own provision provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the several [feature dependencies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/ms476942) using `VisibilityFeatureDependency` but the only alternative is to use custom provision provider.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for my question is

1. Create a new feature
2. Open feature dependencies for the new created feature
3. Add several feature dependency properties
4. Set id of the new created feature to VisibilityFeatureDependency property